# Prove an inequality regarding subsets of $[2n+1]$ of size $n$ can be replaced with an equality

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the family of all subsets of $U = [2n+1] = \{1,2,\ldots,2n,2n+1\}$ with size $n$, $n \ge 3$.

Let $\mathcal{F}_m \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ be a subfamily of $\mathcal{A}$ with minimum size such that any $j \in U$ is contained in at least $m$ sets of $\mathcal{F}_m$, $\binom{2n}{n-1} \ge m \ge 1$. A double counting argument implies:

$$n\vert \mathcal{F}_m \vert \ge (2n+1)m$$

or:

$$\vert \mathcal{F}_m \vert \ge \Bigg\lceil \frac{(2n+1)m}{n} \Bigg\rceil \tag{1}$$

I suspect that the inequality in $(1)$ can be replaced with an equality. Any hint to prove the equality formally?

Comment: You are asking about the existence of an $m$-regular $n$-uniform hypergraph on $2n+1$ vertices, or almost-regular if the divisibility condition is not met. The set $U$ is the vertex-set, and $\mathcal{F}_m$ is the edge-set. It might help you to find resources. I don't know if the result is known for such a high uniformity

Comment: Observation: It would suffice to show that there is a set of cyclic orderings (in number $\binom{2n+1}{n} / (2n+1)$) such that every $n$-subset of $[2n+1]$ is an interval in exactly one of them. E.g., for $n=2$ we can take $12345$ and $13524$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$m=n$:

A simple way to cover the $2n+1$ elements with $n$ subsets of $n$ elements is to take any subset of $n$ elements, and its $2n+1$ circular shifts. (they form a class of subset invariant by shifts). Note that no matter the chosen subset, the corresponding class has $2n+1$ circular shifts because $n$ and $2n+1$ are coprime.

$m=kn$:

Take $k$ distinct classes of subsets invariant by shifts. Note that there are $\frac{1}{n}\binom{2n}{n-1}$ (Catalan number) classes of subsets invariant by circular shift, so we can go up to $m=\binom{2n}{n-1}$.
We can prove this by showing that there are $\binom{2n}{n-1}$ subsets of $n$ elements that contain $1$. For each class of subsets invariant by shift, exactly $n$ subsets contain $1$, so we get $\frac{1}{n}\binom{2n}{n-1}$ classes.

In all of these cases, we have $n|F_m|=(2n+1)m$

$m=r<n$:

Let $c_k$ be the subset $\{kn+1, kn+2, .. (k+1)n\}$ where the values are brought back to the range $\{1, ..., 2n+1\}$ modulo $2n+1$
The $c_k$, $0\leq k < 2n+1$ are all distinct and form a class of subsets invariant by shift. The $c_k$, $0\leq k < \left\lceil \frac{(2n+1)m}{n}\right\rceil$ forms a solution.

$m=kn+r$:

Combine the solution for $m=r$ with $k$ classes distinct from the one used for $m=r$.

Comment: I think the key point is not that $n$ does not divide $2n+1$ but rather that $n$ and $2n+1$ are coprime. This ensures that $n$-subsets always have trivial cyclic symmetry (which would otherwise cause all sorts of issues). Given this fact, the cyclic $C_{2n+1}$-action partitions $[2n+1]^{(n)}$ into orbits of size $2n+1$, and one can just take as many orbits as one needs together with part of one further orbit. +1

Comment: Why do we need $n$ and $2n+1$ be coprime since all $n$ elements are different?

Comment: @FabiusWiesner If $k$ and $n$ are not coprime, we can find some subsets of size $k$ of the set $\{1, ..., n\}$ such that the class of circular permutations has less than $n$ elements (It happens when the subset has a non-trivial automorphism under circular shift). I'm almost sure we could solve your question even in the case of subsets of a size not coprime with the size of the set, but this would complicate the analysis.